# What is the difference in behavior between these two usages of synchronized on a list

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("a");
...
list.add("z");

synchronized(list) {
    Iterator<String> i = list.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

and

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("a");
...
list.add("z");

List<String> synchronizedList = Collections.synchronizedList(list);

synchronized(synchronizedList) {
    Iterator<String> i = synchronizedList.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Specifically, I'm not clear as to why `synchronized` is required in the second instance when a synchronized list provides thread-safe access to the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't lock around the iteration, you will get a ConcurrentModificationException if another thread modifies it during the loop.

Synchronizing all of the methods doesn't prevent that in the slightest.

This (and many other things) is why `Collections.synchronized*` is completely useless.
You should use the classes in `java.util.concurrent`.  (and you should think carefully about how you will guarantee you will be safe)

As a general rule of thumb:

> Slapping locks around every method is *not* enough to make something thread-safe.

For much more information, see [my blog](http://blog.slaks.net/2013-07-22/thread-safe-data-structures)

Comment: Ah, so basically a synchronized list just bombs if more than one thread tries to modify it. It doesn't really protect you in any fashion other than letting you know that more than one thread is trying to access the list?

Comment: @VivinPaliath: The `synchronizedList` will make sure that calling individual methods won't break the collection by racing against each-other.  It doesn't help you make sure that your structure is safe.

Comment: +1 except synchronizedList() is not completely useless, it's just not usually a complete solution.

Comment: @fd.: If you use `synchronizedList()`, you will either need to provide higher-level synchronization (which means you would have enough of your own locks that you won't need it), or you will have race conditions.

Comment: @SLaksL: My point is the reflection of that - if you don't use synchronizedList() you will need to implement the locking that synchronizedList() provides, in addition to the other locking you will need. But I agree that you really need to think about the locking needed and not use conveniences like synchronizedList as a crutch.

Answer (score 3):

`synchronizedList` only makes each call atomic.  In your case, the loop make multiple calls so between each call/iteration another thread can modify the list. If you use one of the concurrent collections, you don't have this problem.

To see how this collection differs from ArrayList.

```
List<String> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>();
list.addAll(Arrays.asList("a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,z".split(",")));

for(String s: list) {
    System.out.print(s+" ");
    // would trigger a ConcurrentModifcationException with ArrayList
    list.clear(); 
}
```

Even though the list is cleared repeatedly, it prints the following because that wa the contents when the iterator was created.

```
a b c d e f g h z
```

Comment: So when you use one of the collections from `java.util.concurrent`  you don't need to explicitly place a lock on the list at all? Just want to make I'm following right...

Comment: @Windle No you don't, the iteration will be done on the list as it was when the iteration started - any changes made to the list during the iteration will be ignored (in your iteration).

Comment: For the concurrency collections, there is no access to any locks, if it uses one. You couldn't lock it if you wanted to, but you shouldn't need to. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey `Arrays.asList("a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,z".split(","))` That's the laziest thing I have ever seen! ;-)

Comment: @assylias There more where that came from. ;)

Comment: @assylias and PeterLawrey - Cool, that makes more sense. Thanks guys =)

Answer (score 2):

The second code needs to be synchronized because of the way synchronized lists are implemented. This is explained [in the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29):

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned list when iterating over it

The main difference between the two code snippets is the effect of the `add` operations:

- with the synchronized list, you have a visibility guarantee: other threads will see the newly added items if they call `synchronizedList.get(..)` for example.
- with the ArrayList, other threads might not see the newly added items immediately - they might actually not ever see them.