# Is constructor-copy of a synchronized Set thread safe?

Tags: java

The easiest way to get a synchronized version of a **java.util.Set** would be using **Collections.synchronizedSet()** like this:

```
Set mySyncSet = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet());
```

The [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) says about this new object that:

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned set when iterating over it

My question is, if I create a copy of this **Set** using a copy constructor like this:

```
Set mySetCopy = new HashMap(mySyncSet);
```

Wil it be thread-safe? (isn't HashMap constructor using iteration to get members of **Set** after all?) or should I manually synchronize the operation like this?:

```
Set mySetCopy;

synchronized(mySyncSet) {
    mySetCopy = new HashMap(mySyncSet);
}
```

Comment: `Collections.synchronized*()` is almost totally useless and should not be used.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12182099/34397

Comment: @SLaks I don't agree that Java's built in Synchronized collections are totally useless. It just depends on the granularity you need (or prefer).

Comment: @RudolphEst: I can't think of any operations in which the granularity provided is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lets take a look at the code:

```
public HashSet(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    map = new HashMap<>(Math.max((int) (c.size()/.75f) + 1, 16));
    addAll(c);
}
```

So that just calls `addAll`,

```
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    boolean modified = false;
    for (E e : c)
        if (add(e))
            modified = true;
    return modified;
}
```

So this loops over the `Collection` you give it.

The answer is therefore no, constructor copy is **not** thread safe.

You need to use your second option and do a explicit `synchronized` on the `Set` before passing it into the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The second way is preferable. If some thread modifies your original thread, while this thread is iterating through your set to copy the references to your new set, you will have trouble.

All code that accesses or modifies the collection should manually synchronize on ***the same instance***... as the JavaDoc specifies.

Comment: Actually, the second way doesn't help, unless all other code locks on the same instance.

Comment: @SLaks agreed, I'll specify that in my answer. I've used synchronized collections in real world multi-threaded applications (mostly Swing GUIs). Aside from performance penalties for locking around reads/iterations the Collections.synchronized* methods are useful. I would recommend a more complex locking/synchronizing system for performance constrained tasks though.

Comment: @RudolphEst I agree entirely. Any non-trivial `synchronization` can be greatly improved by using `Collection`s in `java.util.concurrent` or a [`ReadWriteLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html). The amount of contention caused by locking an `Object` just for read access can be immense.